# Passing pointer to array of objects into function

Tags: c++

When I run this code it crashes with out any errors. I have tried everything i know and done searches but i can figure this one out. It builds and runs fine and goes all the way to the cout in FleetCapacity and something about that line is making the code crash . When i commented out that line the code ran fine so im not sure as to why that line of code is causing my program to crash and burn.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Ship{
private:
    string shipName;
    string shipYear;
public:
    Ship(string sN,string sY){shipName=sN; shipYear=sY;}
    virtual void printInfo();
    void setShipName(string);
    virtual string getShipName();
    void setShipYear(string);
    string getShipYear();
};

class CruiseShip:public Ship{
private:
    int maxPass;
    int maxCrew;
public:
    CruiseShip(string sN,string sY, int mP,int mC):Ship(sN,sY){setShipName(sN);maxPass=mP; maxCrew=mC; }
    void printInfo();
    void setMaxPass(int);
    int getMaxPass();
    void setMaxCrew(int);
    int getMaxCrew();
};

class CargoShip:public Ship{
private:
    int cargoCap;
public:
    CargoShip(string sN,string sY,int cC):Ship(sN,sY){setShipName(sN);cargoCap=cC;}
    void printInfo();
    void setCargoCap(int);
    int getCargoCap();

};


void Ship::setShipName(string sN){shipName=sN;}
string Ship::getShipName(){return shipName;}
void Ship::setShipYear(string sN){shipYear=sN;}
string Ship::getShipYear(){return shipYear;}
void Ship::printInfo(){
cout<<"The ships name is "<<shipName<<endl;
cout<<"The ships year is "<<shipYear<<endl;
}

void CruiseShip::printInfo(){
cout<<"The ships name is "<<getShipName()<<endl;
cout<<"The ships maximum passangers is "<<maxPass<<endl;
}
void CruiseShip::setMaxPass(int mP){maxPass=mP;}
int CruiseShip::getMaxPass(){return maxPass;}
void CruiseShip::setMaxCrew(int mC){maxCrew=mC;}
int CruiseShip::getMaxCrew(){return maxCrew;}

void CargoShip::printInfo(){
cout<<"The ships name is "<<getShipName()<<endl;
cout<<"The ships cargo capacity is "<<cargoCap<<endl;
}
int CargoShip::getCargoCap(){return cargoCap;}
void CargoShip::setCargoCap(int cC){cargoCap=cC;}




void fleetCapacity(Ship** s ,int e){

    cout << "Name of ship: " << s[e]->getShipName() << endl;


}

int main()
{
    const int NUMSHIPS = 3;
    //int aSize = NUMSHIPS;
    // array of ship pointers initialized with addresses of dynamically allocated class objects.
    Ship *ships[NUMSHIPS] = {
                                         new Ship("The Dinghy Berry", "1982"),
                                         new CruiseShip("Disney Adventure Tours"," ",500,100),
                                         new CargoShip("The Sea Trucker"," ", 50)

                                       };

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMSHIPS; i++ )
    {
        ships[i]->printInfo();
    }

   cout << "The entire fleet capacity is: ";
   fleetCapacity(ships, NUMSHIPS);
    cout << " tons." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger spit out on? Programs usually don't crash silently unless you specific did something to.

Answer (score 1):

you are calling `fleetCapacity(ships, NUMSHIPS);` which is then accessing `s[e]` (`ships[NUMSHIPS]`) in the function. The valid indices are `0` through `NUMSHIPS-1`.

Comment: I might be the worst programmer ever.

Comment: Alright so could i use dynamic casting to determine if e[0] is a Ship, CruiseShip or CargoShip ? Or is there a better way to find that out?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want the function to do, but you should use virtual functions to give each ship a different behavior depending on its class instead of using dynamic casts.